# convert datetime (mm/dd/YYYY) to decimal(YYYYmmDD)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am trying to get the following result in Sql:

example: 23/05/2014 to 20142305

but get this:

```
select convert(decimal, convert(datetime, '5/23/2014'))
```

result:41780

anyone know how you can get the following format?? (if possible ??)

regards and thanks

Comment: which RDBMS are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In many databases (including SQL Server), you can just do:

```
select 10000 * year(datetime) + 100 * month(datetime) + day(datetime)
```

Some databases don't support these functions, so you might need `extract(datepart from datetime)` or a similar function.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
SELECT CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), datetime, 112)  AS DECIMAL)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE FUNCTION DateToYYYYMMDD
(
    @Date DateTime
)
RETURNS decimal
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @ResultVar decimal
    SET @ResultVar=Year(@Date)*10000+Month(@Date)*100+Day(@Date)
    RETURN @ResultVar
END
```

You can use it like this

```
Select dbo.DateToYYYYMMDD(GetDate())
```

Remeber,when calling a user function yoy MUST include the schema in this case dbo.

Answer (score 0):

```
select convert(decimal, format(convert(datetime, '5/23/2014'),'yyyyMMdd'))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    CONVERT(NUMERIC,
        CONCAT(
            LEFT('23/05/2014',2)
            ,RIGHT(LEFT('23/05/2014',5),2)
            ,RIGHT('23/05/2014',4)
            )
            )
```

The CONVERT(NUMERIC part may/not be necessary depending on how the value will be used.